# Installation error GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

Tags: python

After following installation instruction and dependency, i encountered below shown error.

```
>>> from healthcareai import SupervisedModelTrainer
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(.:120269): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 15:08:55.041: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
```

Comment: Is that the entire stack trace from python? At first glance, it looks like the DB layer wasn't able to start. Maybe write permission errors? Also, let us know the OS you are encountering this.

Comment: what `installation instruction` do you mean? What code do you run? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.